# Make a TCPServer recieve a multi-line message in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tcp, tcpserver

I have a machine that sends a multi-line message to a TCP/IP Server. However, when I use any simple Ruby Server, I can only receive the first and last lines (as separate messages in separate connections). I've tried using `TCPServer`, `EventMachine` and pretty much everything I could find but now I'm stuck.

The machine is definitely sending the whole message as a quick Python script displays the whole message.

---

### For reference:

---

**One of the Ruby Servers**
*(being used in a Rails project-- in config/initializers)*

```
Thread.new do
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'thread'
    require 'socket'
    require 'ruby-hl7'

    PORT = 2100
    srv = TCPServer.new(PORT)
    puts "proxy_server listening on port: %i" % PORT

    loop {
        Thread.start(srv.accept) do |message|
            puts "Recieved message."
            puts message.read
        end
    }
end
```

**Output from the Ruby Servers**

```
MSH|^~\&|^SureSignsVS||||20070302014355||ORU^R01^ORU_R01|CN212079910000000017|P|2.4|||||||||2.16.840.1.113883.9.2.1


OBX||NM|0002-4182^HR_Pulse^MDIL||87|0004-0aa0^bpm^MDIL|||||F||||||0002-4bb8^SpO2^MDIL|||||||2.16.840.1.113883.9.2.1


OBX||NM|0002-4182^HR_Pulse^MDIL||87|0004-0aa0^bpm^MDIL|||||F||||||0002-4bb8^SpO2^MDIL|||||||2.16.840.1.113883.9.2.1
```

(and then the last line repeats, but this is expected as the machine keeps resending the message every 60secs)

---

**The Python Server**

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.39'
TCP_PORT = 2100
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
conn.close()
```

**Output from the Python Server (expected and ideal output)**

```
MSH|^~\&|^SureSignsVS||||20131124213151||ORU^R01^ORU_R01|CN2120792100000000Q8|P|2.4|||||||||2.16.840.1.113883.9.2.1
PID|||D1234567||^^
PV1|||^^|||||||||||||||A|
ORC|NW|||||||||||||||||CN21207991
OBR||||SPOTCHECK|||20131121190052|||
OBX||NM|0002-4bb8^SpO2^MDIL||100|0004-0220^%^MDIL|||||F
OBX||NM|0002-4a05^NBPs^MDIL||100|0004-0f20^mmHg^MDIL|||||F|||20131121185945
OBX||NM|0002-4a06^NBPd^MDIL||60|0004-0f20^mmHg^MDIL|||||F|||20131121185945
OBX||NM|0002-4a07^NBPm^MDIL||69|0004-0f20^mmHg^MDIL||L|||F|||20131121185945
OBX||NM|0002-4182^HR_Pulse^MDIL||86|0004-0aa0^bpm^MDIL|||||F||||||0002-4bb8^SpO2^MDIL
```

Thank you in advance.